# How to get a more powerful grav drive to jump at least 27 LY?

Tags: starfield

For a quest I have to jump 27 LY. My current grav drive is only made for 25 LY and there is no system closer then the requested 27 LY.

All the ship technicians I asked can not offer a more powerful grav drive then the one I currently already have in my space ship.

What exactly do I need to get more powerful grav drive?
Is this only possible with a bigger ship from a higher class?
Or can I buy such a grav drive from some specific vendors on a specific planet or location only?
Or do I need a specific skill to buy such a grav drive?
Or do I get such a drive after solving a specific quest?

Comment: Without giving away any spoilers, pretty much 'yes' to all your questions. ‍♀️ Also, some companions and skills can also boost range some.

Comment: You'll probably need a B or C class ship, which requires piloting skills and I think starship design skills.

Comment: Just a side note: Is it possible to see who has downvoted my question?

Comment: @PeterCo No, that's (understandably) anonymous. It's nice when people explain their downvotes, but it's unfortunately unlikely the downvoter will see your comment and react to it. If I were to guess, I'd say it was done because you're asking too many questions: it's good to ask a very specific question. Your titular question encompasses all of them, so you might as well remove those additional questions (which look like hypotheses, rather).

Answer (score 4):

For jumping longer distances you have several options:

1. Get a better grav drive. Different starports can offer different items, so check various places. Do not select upgrade when you go to do this, as it only upgrades the same "model" of  Grav Drive. rather you need to go through the ship builder itself to remove/sell your old drive and buy a new one. B and C classes can easily reach 27+, but you might be able to squeeze by with the Helios 300 Grav Drive and combining the next points. There's a decent amount of parts that are "hidden" until you reach a certain level(the last grav drive at 54). so there's no harm in putting your quest aside to grind up your level doing other things.
2. Add more fuel tanks. While it doesn't increase your jump range specifically, it does increase your overall range, So you can go farther.
3. Reduce weight. If your Grav Drive is rated for 30, but you're only getting 25... weight is likely why. You actually might want to do the *inverse* of the previous step, since fuel tanks can be quite heavy. You'll have longer range singular jumps. As an example of how much weigth plays a part... My main ship has a Grav Drive rated for 34, but it's also an overly large cargo hauling battleship so I only get 20 out of it...
4. Upgrade your Astrodynamics skill. Each point increases your jump range by a noticeable amount.
5. Rebuild your ship. Yes this one could be overkill, but if your Piloting Skill is high enough to handle C class ships... and especially if you have points in Starship Engineering... it's time to just build your own. You'll never worry again.