# What's the longest jump between two planets?

Tags: starfield

I'm trying to figure out how to outfit a ship to jump to Charybdis III, and my current ship is a *hair* too underpowered to reach the planet. While I'm trying to improve my astrodynamics score, which should get me jumping far enough to reach it - I feel like knowing what's the 'longest' I need to jump would be helping me upgrade/outfit my 'perfect' ship.

So what's the longest distance between 2 planets?

Comment: If you need some useful hints "how to outfit a ship" for long jumps, please have a look at this answer: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/404609/54377

Comment: Two planets, or two _stars_? I don't think Lightyears come into play when jumping between planets in a single system

Comment: Oh, I generally tend to think of it as planets, but technically I'd guess stars

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I think technically they would be systems, as you can't actually jump to the star itself :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this site](https://www.powerpyx.com/starfield-how-to-fast-travel/) the max distance between two stars in 28 LYs, so a GravDrive of 28 LY or better should do.

In trying to locate this 28 LY jump, I actually found several jumps that were 28.XX LY's away. The longest jump was from Wolf to Alpha Andraste which is 28.518 LY in total, so I'm not sure if a 28 LY GravDrive will cut it, and you might need a 29 LY GravDrive. All of my current ships have 30 LY GravDrives, but I will try and find one with a 28 LY GravDrive to test.